# Musical Floppy Drive

Tags: music, floppy

I was wondering if it would be possible to make a floppy drive installed on your computer play music. I found that it's easy to get tones out of `fdrawcmd` using the cylinder and rate, but is there anything out there actually made for musical floppy drives on ubuntu? And, is it safe for my drive to use `fdrawcmd` to make music?